# After getting latetest update of testng (6.9), not able to run testng.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, webdriver, testng

I just updated my testng plugin in my eclipse IDE, after that I am not able to execute testng.xml, but i am able to execute test case separately by testng.

Notes: I also [submitted this issue](https://dev.eclipse.org/recommenders/community/confess/#/incidents/VXDZLUy9EGbFmVLRL6AxDOfIgjoAEFSZVmNSdGALtWenqCCompAxiJZG0NOb40DS) for eclipse dev team.

please let me know if we have any other way to solve this issue.

Eclipse Versions: Mars (4.5)
Platform Support: Windows -64 bit
Java- 1.8.0.60-b27

Comment: You should check if the issue already exists or create a new one here: https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Do the folowing

1. Delete existing testng plugin
2. restart eclipse
3. Go to install new software and add: http://beust.com/eclipse-old/eclipse_6.9.5.201508210528/
4. install this version of plugin.
5. restart eclipse
6. check if now it works as expected.

In my case this solved the problem.